Who is more likely to get custody, mother's grandparents or non-biological-father divorcing the wife?
Situation:

A husband is divorcing the wife, and he is NOT the biological father of the couple's children

this is because she cheated on him (unknown to him until divorce)
until the divorce time he didn't know he was not the sperm donor.
he's listed legally as the kids' father on birth certificates and there's obvious proof/evidence he always acted as a father to them, etc... The only thing that can be pointed to as "not a father" in front of a judge is the DNA paternity test.


Soon-to-be-ex-wife is incapable of being assigned custody (for example, she's currently incarcerated). The husband is trying to get full custody in the divorce.

Mother's parents wish to get full custody of the kids, based on the fact that the husband is not their biological parent.


In such a case, what is the the realistic likely outcome in terms of custody decision between the husband and his soon-to-be-ex-parents-in-law? To the best of my limited awareness, in a normal divorce, a mother has a good chance to win custody if the father isn't biologically related to the kids; but here it's not the mother but mother's side grandparents.
If jurisdiction matters, let's assume Texas (the question arose after reading a story set there); but honestly I'd be happy with answer in any US jurisdiction

Judge should decide what’s best for the kid(s). And the kids should be asked. And it very much depends on the circumstances.

How old are the children? Are they old enough to have informed opinions about who they should live with?

@Barmar - to simplify the answer, let us assume they are not old enough to qualify for that (IIRC in USA it's somewhere around age 14). Let's say 6-7 years of age, clearly not mature enough to have a useful opinion

@gnasher729 - I don't have a citation but I'm almost certain that "best interest of the child" will NOT be listened to if the husband is not the kid's biological father in a 'normal' divorce, even if he's a better parent as far as custody; unless the mother is absolutely unfit. I could be wrong about that, you are welcome to give examples where a non-bio-dad was given custody when the mother wasn't unfit in a contested custody battle. He will still get hit with child support, but NOT be able to get custody no matter whether he's a better of 2 parents

@user17760, I think you're mis-analysing that situation. When a mother has custody, wishes to retain custody, and is not positively unfit, then a court will never reallocate custody merely on the basis that some other person might be expected to conduct themselves even better as a parent. The reason for this is that the best interests of children are served by the security and resilience of the relationship with the mother. It is not a slavish deference to any biological facts by the courts, but to accumulated experience about the behavioural facts and outcomes.

Close but not quite a duplicate. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17575/do-men-lose-custody-of-children-if-they-are-found-to-not-be-the-biological-fathe?rq=1 and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/is-it-likely-to-win-back-child-support-from-biological-father-of-a-child-whose-c?rq=1

united-states
Short Answer
The husband of the mother is the legal father in this case. Assuming that he is not otherwise an unfit father, the maternal grandparents have a decent chance of securing limited regular visits with their grandchildren, but not primary custody.
The maternal grandparents would ordinarily have standing to claim more than limited visitation only when the children are left with them and the children are not physically either either the husband or the mother, or when the children recently lived with the maternal grandparents away from either the husband or the mother for an extended period of time.
If there was a contest at all, because the husband's status as legal father had not yet become incontestable (typically after one to five years from birth, depending upon the state), the custody fight would be between the husband and the genetic father. If the husband's status as legal father is incontestable, or is not raised in the divorce by someone with standing to do so (typically the mother or a guardian-ad-litem for the children), then the husband's lack of genetic relationship is irrelevant.
Absent a total termination of the mother's parental rights, however, either legally, or due to death, the mother will usually have some visitation to the extent feasible, and some say in making major decisions for her children to the extent feasible.
Long Answer

To the best of my limited awareness, in a normal divorce, a mother has
a good chance to win custody if the father isn't biologically related
to the kids; but here it's not the mother but mother's side
grandparents.

This is true only when the husband wasn't married to the mother at the time the children were born, isn't listed on the birth certificate of the children, and isn't otherwise presumed by law to be the parent of the child. Paternity isn't entirely a matter of genetic parentage. The legal presumption of paternity in a married couple is very strong.
This is purely a matter of state law which is not precisely the same in every U.S. state, commonwealth, territory, or district.
In the fact pattern of the question, the husband of the mother is the legal parent of the children. The details of this analysis are explored, for example, in this Law.SE question.
The maternal grandparents are not (assuming that there is no instance of incestuous parenting).
So, unless the children have been living with the maternal grandparents for an extended period of time, or the children are living with the maternal grandparents at the time of the divorce, the maternal grandparents may not even have standing to ask for more than grandparent visitation.
Custody is only allocated in the best interests of the child among people who have standing to seek it.
For example, in Colorado, standing to participate in parenting decisions is governed by Colorado Revised Statutes § 14-10-123, which states (omitting provisions related to automatic restraining orders and procedural issues imposed in these cases):

(1) A proceeding concerning the allocation of parental
responsibilities is commenced in the district court or as otherwise
provided by law:
(a) By a parent:
(I) By filing a petition for dissolution or legal separation;  or
(II) By filing a petition seeking the allocation of parental
responsibilities with respect to a child in the county where the child
is permanently resident or where the child is found;  or
(b) By a person other than a parent, by filing a petition seeking the
allocation of parental responsibilities for the child in the county
where the child is permanently resident or where the child is found,
but only if the child is not in the physical care of one of the
child's parents;
(c) By a person other than a parent who has had the physical care of a
child for a period of one hundred eighty-two days or more, if such
action is commenced within one hundred eighty-two days after the
termination of such physical care;  or
(d) By a parent or person other than a parent who has been granted
custody of a child or who has been allocated parental responsibilities
through a juvenile court order entered pursuant to section
19-1-104(6), C.R.S., by filing a certified copy of the juvenile court
order in the county where the child is permanently resident. Such
order shall be treated in the district court as any other decree
issued in a proceeding concerning the allocation of parental
responsibilities.
(1.3) As used in this section, excluding subsection (1.5) of this
section:
(a) “Child” has the same meaning as set forth in section 19-1-103(18).
(b) “Parent” has the same meaning as set forth in section
19-1-103(82)(a).
(1.5)(a) For purposes of this subsection (1.5) only, “child” means an
unmarried individual who has not attained twenty-one years of age.
(b) The court may enter an order for allocation of parental
responsibilities for a child, as defined in subsection (1.5)(a) of
this section, and a determination of whether the child shall be
reunified with a parent or parents, when the requirements of
subsection (1) of this section are met, the order is in the child's
best interests, and:
(I) The child has not attained twenty-one years of age;
(II) The child is residing with and dependent upon a caregiver;  and
(III) A request is made for findings from the court to establish the
child's eligibility for classification as a special immigrant juvenile
pursuant to 8 U.S.C. sec. 1101(a)(27)(J).
(c) If a request is made for findings from the court to establish the
child's eligibility for classification as a special immigrant juvenile
under federal law and the court determines that there is sufficient
evidence to support the findings, the court shall enter an order,
including factual findings and conclusions of law, determining that:
(I) The child has been placed under the custody of an individual
appointed by the court pursuant to an order for allocation of parental
responsibilities;
(II) Reunification of the child with one or both parents is not viable
due to abuse, neglect, abandonment, or a similar basis found under
state law;  and
(III) It is not in the best interests of the child to be returned to
the child's or parents' previous country of nationality or country of
last habitual residence.
(1.8) The court shall make all necessary persons parties to the
proceeding pursuant to the requirements of section 19-4-110 and shall
make a determination pursuant to section 19-4-105 as to legal
parentage.
(2) Except for a proceeding concerning the allocation of parental
responsibilities commenced pursuant to paragraph (d) of subsection (1)
of this section, notice of a proceeding concerning the allocation of
parental responsibilities shall be given to the child's parent,
guardian, and custodian or person allocated parental responsibilities,
who may appear and be heard and may file a responsive pleading. The
court may, upon a showing of good cause, permit the intervention of
other interested parties.

In the Colorado example, limited grandparent visitation can be allowed, however, even when grandparents can't be granted primary custody or decision-making authority:

According to Colorado law (C.R.S. §19-1-117), grandparents’ will
have the right to request visitation of grandchildren when:

The grandchild’s parents have divorced, have had their marriage annulled or have legally separated.

Someone other than a parent of the child has been given custody of the child.

One parent of the child may have passed away.


If, in such situations, the court deems that it is in a child’s best
interests to have regular visits with his or her grandparents, then
this visitation may be ordered. In other words, while grandparents may
have the right to request visitation with a grandchild, they do not
necessarily always have the legal right to be granted visitation.

Requests by grandparents for custody in Colorado (either full custody if they have standing as non-parents to ask for it, or limited visitation requests), as a continuing example, are also subject to Colorado Revised Statutes § 14-10-123.3 which states:

Whenever a grandparent seeks parental responsibility for his or her
grandchild pursuant to the provisions of this article, the court
entering such order shall consider any credible evidence of the
grandparent's past conduct of child abuse or neglect. Such evidence
may include, but shall not be limited to, medical records, school
records, police reports, information contained in records and reports
of child abuse or neglect, and court records received by the court
pursuant to section 19-1-307(2)(f), C.R.S.

In most U.S. states, there is a limited time period, often one to five years after a child is born, after which the father's legally established paternity is incontestable for custody and child support purposes by anyone, regardless of the genetic parentage of the child. So the age of the children would be highly relevant.
For example, if the child or children are 6-7 years old, as suggested in a comment, then the paternity of the mother's husband is incontestable, and the lack of a genetic parental relationship is completely irrelevant.
In many U.S. states (perhaps most), the genetic father of the children has no standing to seek to be determined to be the father of a child born to a married woman. So, if neither the father nor the mother nor a guardian-ad-litem for the children contested paternity in the divorce, the birth certificates would be controlling. In this situation, the husband of the mother wouldn't seek to contest paternity, and it would be unusual but not unheard of, for a guardian-ad-litem to be appointed in a plain vanilla divorce with children young enough to have contestable paternity. So, in those states, if the mother didn't raise the issue, the husband's status as legal father would usually be uncontested.
If the mother raised the issue in the divorce and the children were not too old for her husband's paternity to be incontestable, the custody fight would be between the genetic father and the the husband,  not between the maternal parents and the husband. A custody fight between the genetic father and the husband would be decided in the best interests of the children, but would favor the husband if the children had spent several years of their lives with him (e.g. 2.5 and 4.5 years).
Generally speaking, the genetic father's chances of winning would be enhanced if (1) the children were younger, (2) the genetic father had been a part of the children's life in some way (e.g. a live-in, non-incestuous, extended family member such as a paternal uncle of the children who lived in the same household), and/or (3) if the genetic father was in a better position economically to be a parent and/or just was better at parenting than the husband of the mother.
For example, the primary child custody statute in Colorado that applies in divorce cases, Colorado Revised Statutes § 14-10-124 (omitting provisions related to abuse, neglect, rape, domestic violence, for which special rules apply and also omitting repealed subsections, and procedural matters) reads as follows:

(1) Legislative declaration. While co-parenting is not appropriate in
all circumstances following dissolution of marriage or legal
separation, the general assembly finds and declares that, in most
circumstances, it is in the best interest of all parties to encourage
frequent and continuing contact between each parent and the minor
children of the marriage after the parents have separated or dissolved
their marriage. In order to effectuate this goal when appropriate, the
general assembly urges parents to share the rights and
responsibilities of child-rearing and to encourage the love,
affection, and contact between the children and the parents.
(1.3) Definitions. For purposes of this section and section
14-10-129(2)(c), unless the context requires otherwise . . .
(1.5) Allocation of parental responsibilities. The court shall
determine the allocation of parental responsibilities, including
parenting time and decision-making responsibilities, in accordance
with the best interests of the child giving paramount consideration to
the child's safety and the physical, mental, and emotional conditions
and needs of the child as follows:
(a) Determination of parenting time. The court, upon the motion of
either party or upon its own motion, may make provisions for parenting
time that the court finds are in the best interests of the child, with
the child’s safety always paramount, unless the court finds, after a
hearing, that parenting time by the party would endanger the child’s
physical health or significantly impair the child’s emotional
development. In addition to a finding that parenting time would
endanger the child’s physical health or significantly impair the
child’s emotional development, in any order imposing or continuing a
parenting time restriction, the court shall enumerate the specific
factual findings supporting the restriction . . .  and may enumerate
the conditions that the restricted party could fulfill in order to
seek modification in the parenting plan. . . . In determining the best
interests of the child for purposes of parenting time, the court shall
consider all relevant factors, including:
(I) The wishes of the child's parents as to parenting time;
(II) The wishes of the child if he or she is sufficiently mature to
express reasoned and independent preferences as to the parenting time
schedule;
(III) The interaction and interrelationship of the child with his or
her parents, his or her siblings, and any other person who may
significantly affect the child's best interests; . . .
(IV) The child's adjustment to his or her home, school, and community;
(V) The mental and physical health of all individuals involved, except
that a disability alone shall not be a basis to deny or restrict
parenting time;
(VI) The ability of the parties to encourage the sharing of love,
affection, and contact between the child and the other party; . . .
(VII) Whether the past pattern of involvement of the parties with the
child reflects a system of values, time commitment, and mutual
support;
(VIII) The physical proximity of the parties to each other as this
relates to the practical considerations of parenting time; . . .
(XI) The ability of each party to place the needs of the child ahead
of his or her own needs.
(b) Allocation of decision-making responsibility. The court, upon the
motion of either party or its own motion, shall allocate the
decision-making responsibilities between the parties based upon the
best interests of the child. In determining decision-making
responsibility, the court may allocate the decision-making
responsibility with respect to each issue affecting the child mutually
between both parties or individually to one or the other party or any
combination thereof. . . . In determining the best interests of the
child for purposes of allocating decision-making responsibilities, the
court shall consider, in addition to the factors set forth in
paragraph (a) of this subsection (1.5), all relevant factors
including:
(I) Credible evidence of the ability of the parties to cooperate and
to make decisions jointly;
(II) Whether the past pattern of involvement of the parties with the
child reflects a system of values, time commitment, and mutual support
that would indicate an ability as mutual decision makers to provide a
positive and nourishing relationship with the child;
(III) Whether an allocation of mutual decision-making responsibility
on any one or a number of issues will promote more frequent or
continuing contact between the child and each of the parties. . . .
(1.7) Pursuant to section 14-10-123.4, children have the right to have
the determination of matters relating to parental responsibilities
based upon the best interests of the child. In contested hearings on
final orders regarding the allocation of parental responsibilities,
the court shall make findings on the record concerning the factors the
court considered and the reasons why the allocation of parental
responsibilities is in the best interests of the child.
(2) The court shall not consider conduct of a party that does not
affect that party's relationship to the child.
(3) In determining parenting time or decision-making responsibilities,
the court shall not presume that any person is better able to serve
the best interests of the child because of that person's sex.
(3.5) A request by either party for genetic testing shall not
prejudice the requesting party in the allocation of parental
responsibilities pursuant to subsection (1.5) of this section. . . .
(6) In the event of a medical emergency, either party shall be allowed
to obtain necessary medical treatment for the minor child or children
without being in violation of the order allocating decision-making
responsibility or in contempt of court.
(7) In order to implement an order allocating parental
responsibilities, both parties may submit a parenting plan or plans
for the court's approval that shall address both parenting time and
the allocation of decision-making responsibilities. If no parenting
plan is submitted or if the court does not approve a submitted
parenting plan, the court, on its own motion, shall formulate a
parenting plan that shall address parenting time and the allocation of
decision-making responsibilities. When issues relating to parenting
time are contested, and in other cases where appropriate, the
parenting plan must be as specific as possible to clearly address the
needs of the family as well as the current and future needs of the
aging child. In general, the parenting plan may include, but is not
limited to, the following provisions:
(a) A designation of the type of decision-making awarded;
(b) A practical schedule of parenting time for the child, including
holidays and school vacations;
(c) A procedure for the exchanges of the child for parenting time,
including the location of the exchanges and the party or parties
responsible for the child's transportation;
(d) A procedure for communicating with each other about the child,
including methods for communicating and frequency of communication;
(e) A procedure for communication between a parent and the child
outside of that parent's parenting time, including methods for
communicating and frequency of communication;  and
(f) Any other orders in the best interests of the child. . . .

Special rules often apply to parents on military deployments.
So, most of the time, the legal father of the child, i.e. the husband of the mother, would get custody of the children if the mother was completely incapable of having custody due to death, or being an a coma expected to be of an extended duration, or if the parental rights of the mother were legally terminated (e.g. for child abuse or child neglect).
Even if the mother was incapable of living with the children part of the time, however, due to incarceration, or being stuck on a space station, or having to work someplace where the children couldn't be (e.g., if the mother were stationed in a forward operating based in a war zone as a soldier), the mother could usually exercise some joint decision-making authority over the children with the ex-husband if that was feasible given their interaction with each other. Also, keep in mind that custody decisions are not permanent. They can be revisited when there is a substantial change in circumstances, such as a mother's release from prison or return from a foreign military deployment.

"This is true only when the husband wasn't married to the mother at the time the children were born, isn't listed on the birth certificate of the children, and isn't otherwise presumed by law to be the parent of the child." Let's  not pretend that courts don't have a strong bias in favour of the mother during custody disputes between the mother and the father.

@Nick012000 Say that as much as you want, but it isn't nearly as strong or clear cut a situation as you claim. Also, your beef is not with that step of the process. You are complaining about the later best interests analysis (which in this case would be between two persons claiming to be fathers). The OP and this part of the response to the OP, is distinguishing between cases where the husband is the legal father of the child and cases where the husband is not the legal father of the child, which is an utterly reasonable distinction to make. But the OP conflates legal father with DNA father.

Totally amazing answer. Covers all the angles I could think of - thank you!

OP does not "conflate" legal father with DNA father, just to be clear :)  The question's unstated assumption was that the DNA donor wasn't in the picture at all, to contest anything. Unknown, or - if known - not interested in custody.

I was asking based on a fairly large volume of assertions I heard (with no citations) that in custody issues, not being a biological parent carries a material penalty if contested between mother and legal-but-not-biological father; in comparison to contested custody between 2 bio parents who are divorcing. So (making the #s up) a bio dad might get 40% custody in a specific contested custory case, but ceteris paribus, non-bio-dad only would get 30%, or even 10%, or 0%, even if no other factors differed aside from DNA test

"The question's unstated assumption was that the DNA donor wasn't in the picture at all, to contest anything." The unstated assumption is that DNA matters legally. The assertions about bio parent v. mother are actually assertions about legal parent v. mother. While husbands of the mother who are not legal parents are almost always also not DNA parents, the converse is not true, a legal parent doesn't have to be a DNA parent. A stepparent is less likely to get custody than a husband who is a legal parent, but both have standing and if there is no legal parent the stepparent will win by default.

canada
Biology plays a very limited role in this situation. What matters is parentage and guardianship as defined in the relevant province's Family Law Act or equivalent (e.g. Ontario's Children's Law Reform Act), and the best interests of the child.
Typically, parentage is established based on a series of presumptions. In Ontario and British Columbia, for example, a person is presumed to be a parent if they were the birth parent's spouse, or living in a conjugal relationship with the birth parent's spouse, at or around the time of the child's birth.
Parents are guardians of a child unless a court order or agreement establishes otherwise, and only guardians can have parenting time and parental responsibilities.
In the case that the parentage presumption mentioned above is overcome by a DNA test, the father can still apply to be a guardian.
Likewise, for the grandparents to have any parental responsibilities or parenting time, they would need, at minimum to be appointed guardians. They would then further need to secure parenting time or parental responsibilities by agreement or by court order. Both of these steps must be made in accordance with the best interests of the child.
The Ontario Court of Appeal has said that "the best interests of a child is the primary concern in determining custody, and that the wishes of biological parents must give way to a consideration of the child’s welfare" (Re Moores and Feldstein (1973), as quoted in Rodriguez v. Guignard, 2013 ONSC 146).
The Supreme Court of Canada has emphasized that "the law no longer treats children as property of those who gave them birth but focuses on what is in their best interest" (Racine v. Woods, [1983] 2 SCR 173).
Biological ties are omitted from the express list of factors that must be considered in determining the best interests of a child. And "a biological tie in itself should generally carry minimal weight" (B.J.T. v. J.D., 2022 SCC 24).
When appropriate, courts take into account the views of the child when assessing the best interests of the child. The weight to be given to these views depends on their age and maturity. Courts have taken into account the views of a child who was 8 years old, and have said the views of a particular 11-year-old child were owed "considerable weight."

Whatever is in the best interest of the child
australia
Parents remain responsible for the care and wellbeing of their children. In Australian law, parents are the people named on the child’s birth or adoption certificate - whether there is a biological connection is immaterial. Similarly, it doesn’t matter if the parents are “nice” people or not, or if they are in gaol, or on overseas deployment or work 6 months of the year on deep-sea oil rigs.
Prima facie, the court will consider any arrangement that the parents agree to as being in the child’s best interests and will usually not be involved in those decisions.
Where the parents can’t agree the court is available to provide help through mediation or, if that fails, can impose a decision. The factors they consider are spelled out here.

The question was asked in the context of "two parties cannot come to agreement and the court MUST impose a decision".

Also... how can anyone possibly argue that custody by imprisoned parent is in the best interest of the child? (assuming the other parent is "normal" - not abusive, not a criminal, can take care of them). As far as I'm aware, practical physical being able to take care of a child IS taken into account by US courts, including being on deployement, in jail, or even something as simple as "do you live in a small apartment where kids won't fit".

You seem to be confusing “custody” with “living arrangements”

@user17760 Note that the 2 key facts of this answer: 'best interest of the child' and 'biological connection is mostly irrelevant' also hold true in most other (at least Western) jurisdictions and are driving the decision here.

@quarague - I don't have the facts to dispute this (hence my asking) but have heard numerous assertions that "biological connection is mostly irrelevant" is NOT the case in terms of custody (though, unfairly, it is 100% irrelevant as far as child support); and non-bio-dad has very little chance at custody, especially with very minor kids who don't get to state their opinions nor have developed a deep connection to him yet like a teenager would



Soon-to-be-ex-wife is incapable of being assigned custody (for example, she's currently incarcerated). The husband is trying to get full custody in the divorce.

Mother's parents wish to get full custody of the kids, based on the fact that the husband is not their biological parent.



So the children's father, in both legal and conventional terms, wants to retain the custody he already has and has had since the children's birth. He is an adequate parent.
You ask whether a judge is going to overrule the father and reassign custody of his children to the mother's relatives, only because it is now discovered the children are not biologically related to the father, due to a hitherto undisclosed betrayal by the mother.
I don't just think a judge would reject the grandparents application out of hand, but he would quite possibly form a very dim view of their character, their motives, and their ability to look after the interests of the children, merely because they had asked the court for such an extreme, absurd, and upsetting action.

I was looking for a legal opinion slightly more grounded in expertise than "I don't think", sorry
